# Fan control on ASRock X99 Extreme4?

Tags: fan, sensors, lm-sensors

I have a ASRock X99 Extreme4. I'm trying to figure out how to access the fan controls from the cli. Right now, they're not showing up anywhere I can find.

```
$ sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +34.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:         +28.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:         +27.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 2:         +26.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 3:         +28.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 4:         +29.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 5:         +25.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

$ sudo pwmconfig
# pwmconfig revision 6166 (2013-05-01)
This program will search your sensors for pulse width modulation (pwm)
controls, and test each one to see if it controls a fan on
your motherboard. Note that many motherboards do not have pwm
circuitry installed, even if your sensor chip supports pwm.

We will attempt to briefly stop each fan using the pwm controls.
The program will attempt to restore each fan to full speed
after testing. However, it is ** very important ** that you
physically verify that the fans have been to full speed
after the program has completed.

/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
$
```

Any ideas?

Edit: When running `sudo sensor-detect`, part of the report is:

```
Some Super I/O chips contain embedded sensors. We have to write to
standard I/O ports to probe them. This is usually safe.
Do you want to scan for Super I/O sensors? (YES/no):
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x2e/0x2f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               Yes
Found unknown chip with ID 0xc803
    (logical device B has address 0x290, could be sensors)
Probing for Super-I/O at 0x4e/0x4f
Trying family `National Semiconductor/ITE'...               No
Trying family `SMSC'...                                     No
Trying family `VIA/Winbond/Nuvoton/Fintek'...               No
Trying family `ITE'...                                      No
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to get `lm-sensors` detecting all the sensors on your board.

Run `sudo sensors-detect` and accept its defaults and allow it to add the relevant chip modules  to `/etc/modules`.

Then edit `/etc/default/grub`. You need to append `acpi_enforce_resources=lax` at the end of the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX`. Here is a screenshot of mine with the relevant line highlighted.

[image: My /etc/default/grub]

**sudo update-grub** then reboot

When you run `sensors` you should now see the fans detected (plus loads of other sensors).

Now rerun **sudo pwmconfig** and all should be well.

It would be a good idea to create or find a configuration file for your motherboard and insert it in `/etc/sensors.d`.

If done properly this will give meaningful names to all the temperatures, voltages and fan speeds detected, discard outputs from any sensors not connected to anything, set reasonable limits and calculate the values of voltages sensed using voltage divider resistors.

Comment: Updated question with info regarding `sudo sensor-detect`

Comment: I was able to get this working thanks to your mentioning `sensors-detect`. A bit of googling for the the unknown chip that was listed, I found I needed to get the nct6775 module going. After setting that up, the fans and some other measurements showed up under `sensors`.